# In vim 7.4, how to let the popup menu be highlighted?

Tags: vim

After I upgrade my vim to 7.4 in Ubuntu system, I found that the popup menu is too dark(I have tried many colors schemes like evening, dark...)
Is there any solution?

Comment: Which popup menu are you referring to though?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, you could set your own colors in your vimrc (after your `colorscheme` command).

`:help hl-Pmenu` lists 4 highlighting groups for the popup menu. If you never used a highlight group before, have a look at some colorscheme files.

A quick & dirty config using all the same colors because I'm lazy:

```
colorscheme foo
highlight Pmenu      ctermfg=2 ctermbg=3 guifg=#ff0000 guibg=#00ff00
highlight PmenuSel   ctermfg=2 ctermbg=3 guifg=#ff0000 guibg=#00ff00
highlight PmenuSbar  ctermfg=2 ctermbg=3 guifg=#ff0000 guibg=#00ff00
highlight PmenuThumb ctermfg=2 ctermbg=3 guifg=#ff0000 guibg=#00ff00
```

Comment: If you want to update a group that has already a color assigned, I think you have to reset the group first with e.g. `highlight Pmenu NONE`. I am not 100% sure this is mandatory but this is what I have observed when doing some trials.